# Have both Json actionresult and HttpStatusCodeResult as possible outcomes, but only one return

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I like to design my methods with only one return statement, for a various number of reasons (I see it as best practice).

But how can i have a mvc controllers actionresult create a result object, where i can put both a HttpStatusCodeResult into, aswell as a normal Json result?

Both of them inherits from ActionResult.

**Edit:**
**An example of what i have now, but would like to change to only 1 return statement, would be like this:**

```
public ActionResult Test(string inputString = "stack")
{
    try
    {
        int carrots = int.Parse(inputString);
        return Json(new { Data = carrots }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some example code to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could inherit and extend the JsonResult class which adds the Http status code.

```js
public class JsonHttpStatusResult : JsonResult
{
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _httpStatus;

    public JsonHttpStatusResult(object data, HttpStatusCode httpStatus)
    {
        Data = data;
        _httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)_httpStatus;
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like a normal Jsonresult in non-error conditions, and in error conditions, it can be:

```js
var errorModel = new { error = "There was an error" };
    return new JsonHttpStatusResult(errorModel, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply send response code along with your response:

```
Response.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

return Json(new { Data = carrots }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want one return, the simple way of doing it is something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    ActionResult result;
    try
    {
        result = TryGetTheCorrectResult();
    }
    catch
    {
        result = MakeSomeHttpStatusCodeResult();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It really is a matter of taste whether you find that "better" than

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        return TryGetTheCorrectResult();
    }
    catch
    {
        return MakeSomeHttpStatusCodeResult();
    }
}
```

Shorter methods with less local variables can also contribute to code quality, but it all depends on taste I guess.